# How to convert a KML file to a dataframe with rows and columns using python?

Tags: python, kml

So I have this KML file and I used the following code to read it -

```
pip install fastkml
with open("...CUs).kml", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    HBCU=myfile.read()
```

HBCU looks like this -

'\n\n  \n    Map of Historically Black Colleges and Universities (HBCUs)\n    Learn more at https://hbcufirst.com]]>\n    \n      \n        ff646000\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ffa79700\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ff9b5701\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ffd18802\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ff387109\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ff589d0f\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ff7e231a\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n        \n      \n      \n        $[name]]]>\n      \n    \n    \n      \n        ffab4939\n        1\n        \n          https://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png\n        \n ...

(Please note that the above KML file is incomplete.)
I want to convert this to a dataframe such that I have columns and rows -

| State | Name | Description | Geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | First | row |
| Second | row | First | row |

I have multiple such KML files and need to convert all of them into rows and columns.

Comment: I could recommend to use `geopandas`. If you provide a link either to your KML (or its part) or a similar example, I could describe this as a detailed answer.

Comment: Hi. If you post a snippet of the KML then it would be easier to help. The structure of the KML is not clear from the posted dump.